# Cannot find my first app in the app menu. Android

Tags: android

I am trying to launch the default Hello World app but after I launch the emulator, I can never find the application in the menu.

- I have Java SDK
- I have Android SDK (14)
- I have the ADT plugin
- The emulator works fine
- I am using Eclipse

---

```
adb -e install C:\Users\Owner\workspace\FirstApplication\bin\FirstApplication.apk

error: device not found
```

I tried it with the `<>` brackets as well and it said it was incorrect syntax.

What now?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.FirstApplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".FirstApplicationActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After command line adb -e logcat:

```
waiting for device
```

and it stayed that way.

---

---

---

SOLUTION

Install the application using: `adb -e install <apk file path>` within the command prompt. If there is an error like this:

```
error: device not found
```

proceed to restart the adb server using:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

BETTER SOLUTION

1. Turn on Eclipse.
2. Turn on Android Virtual Machine.
3. Ctrl + Alt + Delete
4. Turn off adb.exe prcoess.
5. Run project as Android application.

This is a temporary solution, I would appreciate if someone can find a permanent fix.

Comment: don't use brackets here, it s just a common notation to say "replace by the value". Do you type this when your emulator is running ?

Comment: I didn't do it while it was running.. I'll try again just in case.

Comment: You should adb allows to communicate with an android (emulator or device) but it doesn't create this android...

Comment: I tried both with the emulator running and not running. Still the same message.

Comment: reboot your machine relaunch eclipse, emulator. adb devices should list the emulator. adb -e install should install your stuff on it. Something seems wrong.

Comment: the adb list of devices was empty.

Comment: try to find some support about this problem on Internet. Your emulator should be listed by adb, otherwise you can't communicate neither install your app on it. But it seems strange, eclipse seems to connect and it uses adb. Does eclipse view of logcat display any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install you app?

Did you look in the menu?

try this in a shell / console

```
 adb -e install <your apk>
```

Comment: I looked in the menu, but there was nothing in the books about installing apps, it just said "run". Trying it out now.

Comment: where is the apk file normally located?

Comment: in eclipse, in the build dir of your project.

Comment: i did that step, but it didn't work. I don't get it. I followed each step to the letter. First, Java SDK. Then, Android SDK. Then, Eclipse. Then, Android plugin. I installed the SDK 14 and created an AVD. I created an android project. The books (Hello Android and Android for Dummies) say it's supposed to output Hello World. But the app isn't even in the menu when I run the project. I'm frustrated, I can't make any progress like this. I've even updated the path variable just in case.

Comment: what does eclipse say in its output window when you click run. Does it say it installed and started you app ? If so, did you double check your manifest to see if your activity has been declared properly ? Post your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: [2011-11-27 13:59:00 - FirstApplication] ------------------------------
[2011-11-27 13:59:00 - FirstApplication] Android Launch!
[2011-11-27 13:59:00 - FirstApplication] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-27 13:59:00 - FirstApplication] Performing com.android.FirstApplication.FirstApplicationActivity activity launch
[2011-11-27 13:59:00 - FirstApplication] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD-14'
[2011-11-27 13:59:00 - FirstApplication] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD-14'

Comment: in your question, not in a comment, it will format the xml (if you use the code button)

Comment: anyhow it seems correct. What does the logcat window say so ? (you can also use from command line adb -e logcat)

Comment: it stayed "waiting for device"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I am new to android app development as well. I found a fix for this. In the Eclipse menu go `File>New>Project>Android>Android Project` from existing code. Then in the `Import Project` window, browse to your root directory, and most importantly make sure you **Tick** the `Copy Projects into Workspace` Check Box

Answer (score 0):

For those who like me encountered a similar problem and find this thread ...

The tutorials I have read do not mention that you need to go to
Run > Run Configurations > Android Application > New (icon) 
then setup from there, especially the Target tab.

After that Run > Run As to start the app.